# Android crashes in Android API 21

Tags: java, android

Android app crashes when run on Android 5.0 and working fine in other versions like android 7, 8, 9, 10, 11. The logs are not clear enough to me where is the problem. I appreciate it if anyone tells me what causing the problem.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (23.0.3).
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.slipslop.slipslop, PID: 19454
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (23.0.3).
    at h.h.c.z.l0.e.run(lambda:5)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: h.h.a.b.o.j: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: h.h.b.a.a$f
    at h.h.a.b.o.l0.o(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:6)
    at h.h.c.z.k0.h.onComplete(lambda:2)
    at h.h.a.b.o.a0.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:6)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at h.h.c.z.l0.l$c$b.run(AsyncQueue.java:3)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: h.h.b.a.a$f
    at h.h.a.b.o.n0.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:2)
    at h.h.c.z.l0.i.run(lambda:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: h.h.b.a.a$f
    at l.a.j1.q0.<clinit>(GrpcUtil.java:15)
    at l.a.j1.b.<clinit>(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:5)
    at l.a.k1.e.a(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:1)
    at h.h.c.z.k0.l.call(lambda:6)
    at h.h.a.b.o.n0.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:1)
    ... 4 more
```

Rules in proguard.pro file

```
-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses, Signature, Deprecated, SourceFile, LineNumberTable, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod
-keep class org.slipslop.slipslop.DataModel.CaptainReviewDataModel { *; }
-keep class org.slipslop.slipslop.DataModel.Constants { *; }
-keep class org.slipslop.slipslop.DataModel.CreateRideRequest { *; }
-keep class org.slipslop.slipslop.DataModel.DashboardGraphsModel { *; }
-keep class org.slipslop.slipslop.DataModel.FareEstimationDataModel { *; }
-keep class org.slipslop.slipslop.DataModel.JobHistoryDataModel { *; }
-keep class org.slipslop.slipslop.DataModel.LevelDataModel { *; }
-keep class org.slipslop.slipslop.DataModel.PassengerDataModel { *; }
-keep class org.slipslop.slipslop.DataModel.TopCitiesDataModel { *; }
-keep class org.slipslop.slipslop.DataModel.TransactionListModel { *; }
-keep class org.slipslop.slipslop.DataModel.WarningModel { *; }
-keep class org.slipslop.slipslop.App { *; }
-keep class org.json.* { *; }
```

build.gradle (app) My buildTypes

```
buildTypes {
        release  {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            dependencies {
                implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1'
                implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, the issue is only in Android 5. I have no issue with later versions. And if i run the appliaion in debug mode i get the following errors:

```
08-01 19:11:48.235 3341-3341/org.slipslop.slipslop E/AuthListener: AuthListener is null so its okay
08-01 19:11:53.095 3341-3341/org.slipslop.slipslop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.slipslop.slipslop, PID: 3341
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (23.0.3).
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:534)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$jx84dqgUsF4ojecSMurRqFLFD1Y.run(lambda)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:15)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel.lambda$runBidiStreamingRpc$0$FirestoreChannel(FirestoreChannel.java:109)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.-$$Lambda$FirestoreChannel$ThFui-hvcsrVGYxlBtcTH5vVbvE.onComplete(lambda)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:229)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzy.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:8)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0$ThrottledForwardingExecutor(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java:54)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$ThrottledForwardingExecutor$MfIJbVuxZtLwosAgPzPA-cU66Ko.run(lambda)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;
        at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java:125)
        at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.<clinit>(GrpcUtil.java:197)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.<clinit>(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:90)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.forTarget(OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:115)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:46)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:26)
        at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:76)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.initChannel(GrpcCallProvider.java:113)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6$GrpcCallProvider(GrpcCallProvider.java:256)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.-$$Lambda$GrpcCallProvider$SCD5iiibQ8l4haiO8ofSfE0wIJg.call(lambda)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzy.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:2)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0$ThrottledForwardingExecutor(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java:54) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$ThrottledForwardingExecutor$MfIJbVuxZtLwosAgPzPA-cU66Ko.run(lambda) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.base.CharMatcher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.slipsl
```

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError may occur because of proguard. Please show your proguard.pro file.

Comment: Set `minifyEnabled false` and `shrinkResources false` to disable [proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code). Then try to reproduce error again. If error will not reproduce then something wrong with proguard rules.